# php sessions empty using ssl?

Tags: php, ssl

Lets say i have a page called

https://url.com/test
and https://url.com/test2

```
class Test extends Application {
    # put global things here
    function __construct() {
        $this->library ( 'sessions' );
        $this->helper ( 'active' );
    }

    function test() {
        $this->sessions->set('login',1);
        echo session_id().'<br/>';
        echo $this->sessions->get('login');
    }
    function test2(){
        if (is_get('d')) {
            $this->sessions->del('login');
        }
                echo session_id().'<br/>';
        echo $this->sessions->get('login');
    }
}
```

when i use http://url.com/test and http://url.com/test2

it give me something like

page1

```
326o42a9pblv48c9kb5va1mgorsf35gr39gu0tg8a6umr0rcdrgmasmmtbqvqm0dqa086bn3od07mpc11b65so62c1atrr3cgemaha1
1
```

page2

```
326o42a9pblv48c9kb5va1mgorsf35gr39gu0tg8a6umr0rcdrgmasmmtbqvqm0dqa086bn3od07mpc11b65so62c1atrr3cgemaha1
1
```

but when on https

page1

```
326o42a9pblv48c9kb5va1mgorsf35gr39gu0tg8a6umr0rcdrgmasmmtbqvqm0dqa086bn3od07mpc11b65so62c1atrr3cgemaha1
1
```

page2

```
326o42a9pblv48c9kb5va1mgorsf35gr39gu0tg8a6umr0rcdrgmasmmtbqvqm0dqa086bn3od07mpc11b65so62c1atrr3cgemaha1
```

the 1 is gone.
**the problem is i want to share a session from page test to page test2.**

edit*
here is my sessions class

```
class Sessions {
    private $config;
    public function set($key, $value) {
        if (isset ( $_SESSION [$key] )) {
            return false;
        }

        if (! isset ( $_SESSION [$key] )) {
            $_SESSION [$key] = $value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function get($key) {
        if (! isset ( $_SESSION [$key] )) {
            return false;
        }

        if (isset ( $_SESSION [$key] )) {
            return $_SESSION [$key];
        }
    }

    public function del($key) {
        if (! isset ( $_SESSION [$key] )) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset ( $_SESSION [$key] )) {
            unset ( $_SESSION [$key] );
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function flush() {
        // do we still need this?
        $_SESSION = array ();
        session_destroy ();
        $this->refresh ();
    }

    public function refresh() {
        session_regenerate_id ( true );
    }

    function __construct() {
        $this->config = config ( 'sessions' );

        # doing some importing things
        ini_set ( 'session.cookie_httponly', $this->config ['cookie_httponly'] );
        ini_set ( 'session.gc_probability', $this->config ['gc_probability'] );
        ini_set ( 'session.gc_divisor', $this->config ['gc_divisor'] );
        ini_set ( 'session.hash_function', $this->config ['hash_function'] );
        ini_set ( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', $this->config ['gc_maxlifetime'] );

        # start the engine
        session_start ();
    }
}
```

the config

```
$config['sessions'] = array(
        'gc_probability' => '0',
        'gc_divisor' => '100',
        # 'cookie_domain' => 'www.networks.co.id',
        # http://us2.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php
        'cookie_httponly' => FALSE,
        # SHA512
        'hash_function' => 'SHA512',
        'gc_maxlifetime' => '1800'
);
```

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: are you using some kind of framework you wish to mention?

Comment: nope im useing a custom framework, is this odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you might be using PHP with Suhosin patch, isn't it the case?

If so, check this flag in your settings:

```
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot = On.
```

This basically tells the server, that the session key depends on document root, which get's changed when you switch http to https.

**edit**: You should have this set to Off in you php.ini, or in case of using multiple ini files, like in debian, there is probably file like suhosin.ini in conf.d subdirectory, where php.ini resides. Not sure, whether it's possible to change this setting through ini_set()

On unrelated note, are you sure, that you want to set gc_probability to 0? That effectively disables session garbage collection.

Comment: im still finding how to turn it on like ini_set ( 'suhosin.session.cryptdocroot', 'On' ); ?

Comment: suhosin.session.encrypt = Off anyway does that matter ?